# Dates not changing in ads rotate plugin wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, ads, banner

I have site on WordPress with plug-in banner ads [AdRotate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/adrotate/).
After I installed the new WordPress version, all new advert dates are  January 1970, and I have AdRotate configuration errors in my dashboard. I can edit  existing advertisements without problem. 
I optimized the database, cleaned the database and re-evaluated all ads, but it didn't solve the problem.  Any guess?

Comment: Cleaned up grammar and spelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you entered the correct dates when editing/creating the adverts.

Also make sure you’ve clicked the green "update now" or "finish update" banner along the top of the dashboard if there is one.

Still not solved then take backup & try solution,

1. check database table "wp_adrotate_schedule" and make sure you have

`id, name, starttime, stoptime, maxclicks, maximpressions, spread, hourimpressions, daystarttime, daystoptime, day_mon, day_tue, day_wed, day_thu, day_fri, day_sat, day_sun`

if not this will help

`ALTER TABLE wp_adrotate_schedule
  ADD (spread char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  hourimpressions int(15) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  daystarttime char(4) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000',
  daystoptime char(4) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000',
  day_mon char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  day_tue char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  day_wed char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  day_thu char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  day_fri char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  day_sat char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  day_sun char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y')`
[how it should look (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56uuD.png)

2. check database table "wp_adrotate" and remove if these fields are exist

`timeframe, timeframelength, timeframeclicks, timeframeimpressions`
[which fields to remove (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k55R.png)

3. after that database changes go to your admin panel and AdRotate > Settings > Maintenance tab & click clean database button.

Answer (score 0):

@Prashant Jayswal thank's for your answer, maybe it is a solution, I didn't try, because I have a simplest one - I renew the add for 7 days and the error has gone!